# x86 Assemby : Finding length of string taking by user

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

I am trying to find number of characters in string taken by user.However lengthof returns me initializing size of string

This is my code , it returns 11

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data

MAX = 10                
stringIn BYTE MAX+1 DUP (?) 

.code
 main PROC

      mov  edx,OFFSET stringIn
      mov  ecx,MAX          
      call ReadString

      call writeString
      mov eax,lengthof stringIn
      call writeint

main ENDP

END main
```

Comment: Iterate over the characters until you find a `'\0'`, unless `ReadString` returns the length for you (check the documentation for the library you're using).

Answer (score 2):

The length of the string returns in register `EAX` after calling `ReadString` :

- http://math.uaa.alaska.edu/~afkjm/cs221/handouts/procedures.pdf
- http://programming.msjc.edu/asm/help/source/irvinelib/readstring.htm

Search the text "readstring" in next example :

- http://cursos.itam.mx/akuri/2004/OPC/MASM615/Examples/Lib32/Irvine32.asm